# Voice audio comes weird and very low with a headphone

Tags: 12.04, sound, volume-control

I had no problems watching videos until yesterday when I rebooted Ubuntu after an upgrade. Now when I watch a video with voices I only hear the background sounds normally but when someone speaks in the video the voices are weird and very low volume.

This problem only happens with the headphones connected - when I disconnect them the sound of voices is also good. The headphones are working with other computers.
Can anyone help me?

Let me know what information you need.

Thanks

Daniel

**EDIT:**

Requested information:

`wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh`

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a0700d9055d6c2951c205d9c851c83420e6be44e

Comment: Have you tried booting a Live-CD to see if the problem persists? If it does, your headphone jack may be broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution, or i think is a workaround.
i went to "Sound Settings" and with the headphones connected I move the "Balance" option to right or left a little bit and the voice sound was fixed.

Daniel

Comment: This is still an issue on 16.04! (your fix/workaround also still works!)

Comment: I just had the same issue - found this post and moving the balance (to the left) worked for me as well. Linux Mint 17.3 - kernel 4.4.0-124-Generic!

Comment: Still an issue on 20.04 and this solution weirdly works. I went to one direction all the way and the audio got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your headphones or check with another headphones. It looks like both stereo channels are shorted and audio driver is trying to "correct" situation.